# "Someone else is already using the program under this name. Please use a different username or try again later"

Tags: windows

> Someone else is already using the program under this name. Please use a different username or try again later

This message appears whenever I try to open a Simply Accounting 2011 file. I can log on as any other user (other than the other person logged in). They cannot log in using my username and password, and I can log in using SysAdmin.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Simply Accounting program, but is the file supposed to be a "shared worksheet" like what Excel users have sometimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a google search and ended up at the Sage searchable knowledge base and your issue was listed along with suggested steps to resolve the issue:

Knowledge Base:
https://customers.sagenorthamerica.com/irj/portal/anonymous/kbsearch

Suggested Resolution:
https://customers.sagenorthamerica.com/irj/go/km/docs/sageKM/Simply%20Accounting%20by%20Sage/Ungated%20Customers/simply22795.html

Comment: After I asked the question, I chatted to their tech support who told me to do that. I feel stupid not trying it before, but I couldn't find the exact wording in their knowledgebase. Thanks though, you got marked as the answer :)

Comment: The Sage Knowledgebase (a.k.a. Sage Customer Portal) seems to have moved to https://support.na.sage.com/selfservice/microsites/msbrowse.do?UMBrowseSelection=SG_SAGE50_U_S_EDITION_1.  The above answer might be at https://www.sagecity.com/ca/sage_50_accounting_ca/f/sage-50-ca-general-discussion/60371/connection-manager-issue-with-new-install.